# Where can I find a dataset of drones attacks?

Tags: data-request, military

I'm looking for a dataset of drone attacks containing:

- attack location (GPS coordinates if possible)
- number of injuries and deaths
- time and date

Optionally:

- demographics information on casualties
- reason for attack
- organization/country piloting the attack

Answer (score 10):

I found at least one non-profit that <s>[has a website](http://natsec.newamerica.net/drones/pakistan/analysis)</s> ([updated link](http://securitydata.newamerica.net/drones/pakistan-analysis.html)) that contains statistics based on specific country. I don't know how accurate they are because many attacks are probably still unknown. I don't know if you can download their data as a database, but I think with finite data points, you can reconstruct the data set yourself.

For the optional stuff:

- **Demographics**: are sort-of there (Militants killed, Civilians killed, Unknown killed, Target organization)
- **Reason for attack**: you may have to dig up media stories for specific attacks and then join that info with the data set
- **Organization/country piloting the attack**: this website has organization and is sorted by country.

I would start by reaching out to this organization (or any other similar ones) and ask if you can take an export of their data set. They use a [Creative Commons license](http://www.newamerica.net/about/copyright), so they encourage non-commercial use with attribution.

Answer (score 6):

The [Bureau for Investigative Journalism](http://www.thebureauinvestigates.com/) was listed as the source for the well-known [Pitch Interactive Drone](http://drones.pitchinteractive.com/) visualization project. Pitch doesn't link directly to the data file they used, but poking around on the BIJ website leads to [this page](http://www.thebureauinvestigates.com/category/projects/drones/drones-graphs/?view=all).

Unfortunately, from clicking around I can't find any sign of well-structured, downloadable data, probably because it is rarely precise or absolutely confirmed.