# Dataset of accidents and incidents involving drones

Tags: data-request

I am looking for a data set listing accidents and incidents involving drones, with as many following fields as possible:

- timestamp
- location
- number of casualties
- description of the accident/incident

Comment: You mean non-military drones? http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/1645/1511

Comment: @philshem Yes. Customer/personal drones.